# Programmatically get Android first activation date

Tags: android

I'm trying to programmatically find my phone's first activation / unboxing / last factory reset date. I know that there isn't an API for that, but I tried a few things:

1) `PackageInfo.firstInstallTime()` for a system package
2) `BUILD.Time`
3) `new File("/proc/cpuinfo").lastModified()`

But none of them gave the exact true date. Any ideas ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Android doesn't have any mechanism to store “unboxing" date. Even if it manages to do so, it'll get formatted after the first factory reset.

Comment: @Swap, I wouldn't mind getting the date of the last factory reset either.

Comment: @amitooshacham, did you find anything that help to get the unboxing date or the first activation ?

Comment: @WaelAbo-Aishah nope, sorry.

Comment: @amitooshacham did you got the answer ? I am also facing the same problem ..